# Internal Server Error when I send my own certificate to Azure Cloud Service

Tags: asp.net, azure

I'm trying to access the Azure Elastic Scale Split/Merge tool from an ASP.NET application. I can open the page in my browser after I use the certificate that I uploaded on Azure. But when I try to connect to the page in ASP.NET I keep getting `500 Internal Server Error`, even though I used the certificate in my request.
Is there something wrong with the code below? Have I been forgetting something?

```
var handler = new WebRequestHandler();
handler.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
handler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual;
handler.ClientCertificates.Add(Cert); //Cert is the X509Certificate2 I use

using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
{
    try
    {
        var response = await client.GetAsync(Endpoint); //Endpoint = https://foobar.cloudapp.net/
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var a = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        throw;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found where I went wrong. When creating the Certificate I was using the .cer file, but it works now with the .pfx file